# Location of generic text print driver

Tags: windows-7, drivers, printer, printing

I have been trying to get an old Epson receipt printer working on a computer running Windows 7.  The problem is the generic text driver literally does not exist on the list of Windows 7 drivers.

I was able to share a printer using the generic text driver, and install it networked to the computer without the driver.  I believe this should have copied over the relevant driver files.  Where could I find the .inf file for the generic text driver?

Thanks!

** The printer also is connected via a serial to usb adapter.

Comment: Printing a test page from the computer in question would probably give me the location right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you've installed the generic drivers using a share, you should be able to print a test page on the computer with the a share to get the location of the driver files (or at least the names), as you mentioned in comments.

However, now that you have them installed, they should show up in the `Add A Printer` menu when you do a manual setup. If they don't there's a chance that they did not install correctly. You'd have to go through this step anyway in order to install the printer, I'm assuming.

Comment: Gotcha, yes I did try doing this, instead of the Generic Text Only driver, the only generic driver given is: Generic Color PS for Commercial Printing which does not work.  Printing remotely works fine.  I went to Devices and Printers > selected shared printer > Print server properties > Drivers > Generic / Text Only and got a list of driver files.  There is no .inf file in the list I can have windows point to however.  I have been doing this remoting in, I know the shared printer works, but have been able to see the test print page.  I assume they are the same.

Comment: HAVE NOT* been able to see the test page.

Comment: Does anyone have a link or copy of the Generic / Text only drivers?  Where are these drivers normally located?

Comment: I reinstalled windows and added a printer pointing to COM4, the location of serial to usb adapter and printer.  It installs fine, but the printer does not receive any print jobs/test page.  Any ideas here?